# cast to type "List" is not allowed

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Below is my code.

```
struct movie {
    char movie_name[30];
    float score;
};


typedef struct movie ITEM;

typedef struct node {
    ITEM item;
    struct node* next;
}NODE;

typedef struct list {
    NODE* head;
}List;
void read_file(List *p_head)
{...

List new_movie = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
...
}
```

I want to to allocate type of 'List' memory.

But I can't allocate.

What's wrong?

Comment: instead do `List new_movie;`

Comment: malloc allocates memory and returns a pointer to it. I would say that you have to do `List *movie = malloc(sizeof(List));` to allocate memory for the head and don't forget that you have to do the same for each NODE. If you still have further issues please update your post with a minimum running example such that we can help further.

Comment: malloc returns pointer, you have to make new_movie pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use malloc, you should assign its return value to a pointer:

```
List *new_movie = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
```